# How find all this positive of $n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a number of the form $a^2+b^2$ with $a,b\in N^{+},(a,b)=1$, such that
every prime  $P \lt \sqrt{n}$ satisfies $P|ab$. Find all such positive integers $n$?

I find $n=5$, and $n=13$,are there any others?

when $n=5$,then $a=2,b=1$, and $P=2<\sqrt{5}$

when $n=13$,then $a=3,b=2$,and  $P=2$ or $3$

Comment: I took the liberty of rewriting your original question, which was very hard to read.

Comment: $n$ is maximum of the primitive Pythagorean triplet.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: Where's the part which said $P \in (a_1, a_2 \dots a_n)$?

Comment: @Inceptio I believe there is more to it than just primitive Pythagorean triplets. The additional condition $P \mid ab,P \lt \sqrt{n}$ is unrelated to Pythagorean triplets

Comment: The actual problem stated every prime less than $\sqrt{n}$ divides $ab$.

Comment: oh,Thank you @EwanDelanoy

Comment: @Inceptio yes,I’ll correct that.

Comment: @math110: You have to arrive at the contradiction.I get no solutions other than $n=13,5$ .

Comment: Thank you, How arrive at the contradiction? @Inceptio

Comment: I'm thinking on that. $a=p_1p_2 \dots p_n$, $b=q_1q_2 \dots q_n$, $a^2+b^2=n$, you know that $t_i$ is any prime, $t_i<\sqrt{n}$ , let largest of  $\{t_1,t_2 \dots t_k)$ is $t_k$. But $t_k \not |ab$, to have $t_i |ab$, you need to have $ab= t_1t_2 \cdots t_k.$, if you have such configuration, the value of $n$ increases and thus $\sqrt{n}$ increases.

Comment: Does $(a, b) = 1$ denote $\operatorname{gcd}(a, b) = 1$?

Comment: yes,@Sp3000,Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First note that $\prod\limits_{p<\sqrt{n}, p \text{prime}}{p} \mid ab$. Thus $n=a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab \geq 2\prod\limits_{p<\sqrt{n}, p \text{prime}}{p}$.

If $n \geq 26$, then $\sqrt{n}>5$, so $n \geq 2\prod\limits_{p<\sqrt{n}, p \text{prime}}{p} \geq 2\prod\limits_{p \leq 5, p \text{prime}}{p}=60$. This implies that $\sqrt{n}>7$, so $n \geq 2\prod\limits_{p<\sqrt{n}, p \text{prime}}{p} \geq 2\prod\limits_{p \leq 7, p \text{prime}}{p}=420$. This implies that $\sqrt{n}>19$, so $n \geq 2\prod\limits_{p<\sqrt{n}, p \text{prime}}{p} \geq 2\prod\limits_{p \leq 19, p \text{prime}}{p}=199399380$. This implies that $\sqrt{n} \geq \sqrt{199399380}>\sqrt{100000000}=10000$.

Let $k=\lfloor \frac{\sqrt{n}}{16} \rfloor$, so $624=\frac{10000}{16}-1 \leq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{16}-1<k \leq \frac{\sqrt{n}}{16}$. We have $16k \leq \sqrt{n}$. Also, $\sqrt{n}<16(k+1)$ so $n<256(k+1)^2$.

By Bertrand's postulate, there exists primes $p, q, r, s$ with $k<p<2k<q<4k<r<8k<s<16k \leq \sqrt{n}$. Thus $256(k+1)^2 \geq n \geq 2\prod\limits_{p<\sqrt{n}, p \text{prime}}{p} \geq 2pqrs>2(k)(2k)(4k)(8k)=128k^4>64k^4$. Thus $4(k+1)^2>k^4$, so $2(k+1)>k^2$ so $k \leq 2$, a contradiction.

Therefore $n \leq 25$. Note that $25 \geq n=a^2+b^2>\max(a^2, b^2)$, so $a, b \leq 4$. If $n \geq 10$, then $\sqrt{n}>3$ so $2(3) \mid ab$. WLOG assume $3 \mid b$, so that $b=3$, so $2 \mid a$, so $a=2, 4$. This gives $n=2^2+3^2=13$ and $n=4^2+3^2=25$, which are both solutions.

Otherwise $n \leq 9$, so $9 \geq n=a^2+b^2>\max(a^2, b^2)$, so $a, b \leq 2$. $a, b$ cannot be both $2$, so we have $n=1^2+2^2=5$ and $n=1^2+1^2=2$, which are both solutions.

In conclusion, all solutions are given by $n=2=1^2+1^2, n=5=1^2+2^2, n=13=2^2+3^2, n=25=4^2+3^2$.

Comment: It's very nice,Thank you ,Your are Master of mathematics!!